# How can I 'resolve' Future in rust?

Tags: rust, concurrency

I'm learning concurrency in rust and can't find a simple example how to return and resolve a `Future`.

How can I implement this javascript code in rust? It seems like I have to implement the `Future` trait on some struct and return it (right?), but I want a straightforward example. Instead of `setTimeout` it can be anything, just keep it simple.

```
function someAsyncTask() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("result")
    }, 1_000)
  })
}
```

Comment: In Rust, the Future is not only the primitive which holds the result, its actually the thing _which does the computation_. This means, yes, you need to `impl Future` for some struct. If you just want to rewrite the example in Rust, you can however use [`tokio::timer::Delay`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/timer/struct.Delay.html) instead. Await it in a async fn and then return your desired result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest analogue in Rust futures to JavaScript's `Promise` constructor is the *oneshot channel*, as seen in [`futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/channel/oneshot/index.html) and [`tokio`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html). The “sender” of the channel is analogous to the `resolve` function, and the “receiver” of the channel is a `Future` that works like the `Promise` does. There is no separate `reject` operation; if you wish to communicate errors, you can do that by passing `Result` in the channel.

Translating your code:

```rust
use futures::channel::oneshot;

fn some_async_task() -> oneshot::Receiver<&'static str> {
    let (sender, receiver) = oneshot::channel();
  
    set_timeout(|| {  // not a real Rust function, but if it were...
      sender.send("result").unwrap()
    }, 1_000);
  
    receiver
}
```

Note that just like you only need `new Promise` in JS if you are translating something callback-like into the promise world, you only need to do this in Rust if you need to cause a future to complete from an outside event. Both should be fairly rare.

Answer (score 5):

The most straight forward `fn() -> impl Future` you can create is to simply use a `async` function:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;

async fn some_async_task() -> &'static str {
    time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1_000)).await;
    "result"
}
```

If you 'remove' one layer of syntax sugar this becomes the following `fn` returning an `async` block.

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use std::future::Future;

use tokio::time;

fn some_async_task() -> impl Future<Output = &'static str> {
    async {
        time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1_000)).await;
        "result"
    }
}
```